# Application shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Where are the application shortcuts (Settings -> XFCE 4 Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts) saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this file  see if that is what you are looking for.

> ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml